# Is there a passive voice of verb smell?

Tags: passive-voice

Is it right to say:

```
No smoke can be smelled in the office.
```

or is there a better description?

Comment: Would you please tell us some more about the situation and what you mean to say? For example, do you mean that people are not permitted to bring the smell of smoke into the office? Or that the office used to smell of smoke, but now it has been thoroughly cleaned and no one can smell smoke there anymore?

Comment: Verbs don't have voices - clauses do. Passive clauses contain verbs in participle form, either past particle or present particle. Your sentence is fine, using the past particle form of 'smell'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"No smoke can be smelled  in the office"

The verb "smell" is both transitive and intransitive. It has been used as a transitive verb in the above sentence. So the sentence in the passive voice is grammatically correct.

Alternatively, we can say in the active voice as follows:

We can smell no smoke in the office.

Comment: Snailboat, you are right. I didn't finish my sentence. I have done it per your advice.